# Use RegEx to breakdown an html source

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to separate every single tag from a HTML source that I'm receiving.

It's a huge piece of code that I'm receiving and I'm trying to make it more 'readable', for a human analysis.
This far I only made up to this RegEx code:

```
RegEx(<\w*>.*<\/\w*>)
```

But this get the beggining of the `!DOCTYPE` tag and run 'till the `</html>`.

And what I'm trying to do is to select each tag individually, independent of the type.
Also, I'm running this RegEx with JavaScript.

Any suggestions are very welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the immediate problem is trivial. You need to make your wildcards [lazy instead of greedy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

i.e. you want to change `*` (match all you can that matches the previous thing) to `*?` (match as little as you can that matches the previous thing but still lets you match the next thing)

… but then your code will break if there is a `>` inside an attribute value, or a script element, or a style element, etc.

Parsing HTML is not trivial. [Regular expressions are not a good tool for it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) Use an existing library instead.

Comment: In this time I've changed my mindset to try solve the problem on different ways, and found a nice library, as you recomended. Jsoup, and seems nice.Though the tip with using the `*?`. Thank you very much :D